# String static member error

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008

I am making a basic program which takes some input and prints it back but I am getting strange error about my static variable.Please help me out.Thanks

Code:

```
/*

    Date:5th January 2011
    Programmer:Fahad
*/
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
class Persons //A class that will store the name,addresses and id numbers of the users
{
    private:
        string name_;
        string address_;
        int id_number_;

    public:
        static int count;//This is the count of the objects created
        Persons();
        void getData(int n);
        void displayData(int n);
        //~Persons();
};
static int count;//initializing the static member
int main()
{
    cout << "Enter Number Of Persons:";
    int n;//This is the number of objects that the user wants to make.
    cin >> n;
    Persons *ptr;//A pointer that will be used for the dynamic memory allocation.

    /*Exception Handling*/
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    try
    {
        //ptr=new [sizeof(Persons) * n];
        ptr=new Persons[n];
    }
    catch(bad_alloc xa)
    {
        cout<<"Sorry,Program Can Not Continue";
        cin.get();
        exit(1);
    }
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    for(int i = 0; i< n; i++)
    {
        ptr[i].getData(n);
    }
    for(int j = 0; j< n; j++)
    {
        ptr[j].displayData( n );
    }
    cin.get();
    delete[] ptr;
    return 0;
}
/*Function Definitions*/
Persons::Persons()
{
    name_="";
    address_="";
    id_number_=0;
    count++;
}
void Persons::getData(int n)
{

        cout<<"Enter Name (Press '$' To Exit):";
        getline(cin,name_,'$');
        cout<<endl<<"Enter Address (Press '$' To Exit):";
        getline(cin,address_,'$');
        cout<<endl<<"Enter Identitiy Card Number:";
        cin>>id_number_;

}
void Persons::displayData(int n)
{

        cout<<"Name:"<<name_;
        cout<<endl<<"Address:"<<address_;
        cout<<endl<<"Identitiy Card Number:"<<id_number_;

}
```

Error:

```
------ Build started: Project: new, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
Compiling...
program.cpp
c:\documents and settings\1\my documents\visual studio 2008\projects\new\new\program.cpp(23) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
Build log was saved at "file://c:\Documents and Settings\1\My Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\new\new\Debug\BuildLog.htm"
new - 1 error(s), 0 warning(s)
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of

```
static int count;//initializing the static member
```

write

```
int Persons::count;
```

Answer (score 2):

Your program has two problems

Problem no 1) Missing declaration for `exit(1);`. 
Solution : Include `<cstdlib>`

Problem no 2) static member `count` declared but not defined. 
Solution : Define the member as `int Persons::count;` instead of `static int count`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define the static variable as `int Persons::count;` Also, your `getData` & `displayData` syntax is wrong. You need to use `->` operator instead of `.` operator.